# Java, native app and global path

Tags: java, java-6

I need to execute a batch file (in Java 6) and use following code for this:

```
final String command = "C:\Ruby191\bin\mygem.bat inputfile.dat";
final File parent = new File(aParentDir);
Process proc;
proc = aRuntime.exec(command, null, parent);
```

But I get this exception:

```
...Exception: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program &quot;
C:\Ruby191\bin\mygem.bat&quot; (in directory &quot;src\test\resources\...
&quot;): CreateProcess error=267, Directory name invalid
```

The batch file in question exists in the specified directory.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: try to use an array of files and exec them in cycle.

Comment: Please don't add noise like "TIA" or a sig. to posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using double backslashes `\\` or single slashes `/` instead of single backslashes. Check current directory name too.